# Has “if I was” be­come gram­mat­i­cally cor­rect in a south­ern US di­alect?

Tags: grammaticality, dialects, subjunctive-mood, register, irrealis-were

Liv­ing my whole life in Arkansas in the United States, I’m cer­tain
that *if I were* is never used by lo­cals. In­stead, phrases like
*if I was* and *you was* and *they was* have all re­placed their
equiv­a­lents in other re­gions.

I’ve heard these so of­ten that I think it’s nec­es­sary to ask if
they are gram­mat­i­cally cor­rect as a part of a south­ern di­alect.
Does their ap­pear­ance in a cer­tain re­gion as ac­cept­able ex­cuse
their ap­pli­ca­tion in for­mal writ­ing?

Per­son­ally, I in­deed be­lieve that any­thing not found in generic,
“ac­cent-free” ar­eas should not be con­sid­ered cor­rect. But
of­fi­cially within a south­ern U.S. di­alect, are these con­struc­tions
gram­mat­i­cal?

Comment: What does "*officially within a southern US dialect*" mean? What officials are involved in deciding this?

Comment: By official, I mean "is it okay, because it's a dialect?" or is it still incorrect whether it's commonplace or not.

Comment: OK to whom, in what context? Primarily opinion-based.

Comment: Can you please name a single *generic, "accent-free" area* in the US, in the world?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question is the stuff grammar wars are fought over.

Personally, I don't think I've ever heard anyone say "if I were", and I've lived all over the US *except* the south. The lay idea being, you would say, "I was a king," not, "I were a king," so why should you say, "If I were a king," instead of, "If I was a king"?

This is called the "subjunctive mood" and is used to indicate that the statement is untrue or wistful. "If I were..." or "I wish I were..." are the typical structures for "subjunctive mood" statements.

So, is it now grammatically correct to dispense with the subjunctive mood? That's a matter of opinion, but if you ask most people they'd probably say, "What's a subjunctive mood?" If I was braver, I would voice my preference.

Comment: I wonder if this is the kind of thing where you tend to hear it like you say it, regardless of what other people actually say? I use *if I **were*** (native AmE speaker), and I just realized I've been singing Megan Trainor's song *Me Too* (and hearing her sing it in my head) that way for months, even though she actually uses *if I **was** you*.

Comment: Textbook answer. So nice to spot a little bit of humor/humour creeping into the last sentence of your answer.